# creating a new column based on observations in other columns

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am having trouble creating a new variable using conditions, I've tried data steps but to no avail.

My data set looks like this right now:

```
A B C D E
1 . 1 1 .
. 1 . . . 
1 . 1 . 1
```

I need to look like this

```
A B C D E R
. .  .  . 1
. 1 . . . .
. . . . . 1
```

So the idea that i've used is if the sum of a -- d is greater than 1 then set R equal to 1 else .  and then drop the observations if 1 is present in a & b & c & d & e but its not doing it for me perhaps its due to missing values.

code i've used so far:

```
data campZ;
set campY;
select;
when (sum(Macroscopic -- Symbolic > 1)) Random = 1;
otherwise; end; 
run;
```

I've tried Proc SQL as well but I have been mainly focusing on the data step but any help will be great.

Thank you!

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to both SET R and clear the other variables.  You need to add the `OF` keyword when using a variable list as an argument to a function.

```
data campZ;
  set campY;
  if sum(of Macroscopic -- Symbolic) > 1 then do;
     Random = 1;
     call missing(of Macroscopic -- Symbolic);
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E,
       CASE WHEN A+B+C+D > 1 THEN 1 END AS R
FROM   Table;
```

(Apologies if I've made any syntax slips, my SAS SQL is a bit rusty.)

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't give me the desired output but it's solved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a query to do this . . . although I think a data step is quite reasonable.  Here is one way to do the above in `proc sql`.

```
proc sql
    select (case when cnt <= 1 then a end) as a,
           (case when cnt <= 1 then b end) as b,
           (case when cnt <= 1 then c end) as c,
           (case when cnt <= 1 then d end) as d,
           (case when cnt <= 1 then e end) as e,
           (case when cnt > 1 then 1 end) as r
    from (select z.*,
                 ((case when a is null then 0 else 1 end) +
                  (case when b is null then 0 else 1 end) +
                  (case when c is null then 0 else 1 end) +
                  (case when d is null then 0 else 1 end) +
                  (case when e is null then 0 else 1 end)
                 ) as cnt

          from campz z
         ) z ;
```

This just returns the values.  If you want them in a new data set, then use `create table as`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked beautifully! can you explain what" from campz z
         ) z ;"  means?

Comment: The expression `campz z` assigns the alias `z` to `compz`.  Table aliases are an important part of the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

data a;
input A B C D E;
cards;
1 . 1 1 .
. 1 . . . 
1 . 1 . 1 
;

proc sql noprint;
create table a1 as
select *, case 
when sum(a,b,c,d,e)>1 then 1
when sum(a,b,c,d,e)<=1 then . 
end as R from a;
update a1 set A=., B=., C=., D=., E=.
where R=1;
quit;

OutPut

Obs A   B   C   D   E   R
1   .   .   .   .   .   1
2   .   1   .   .   .   .
3   .   .   .   .   .   1